# Splitting character string in R - Extracting the timestamp

Tags: r, strsplit

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

I am attempting to clean some data in R where a time stamp and a text string are included together in the same cell. I am not getting the expected result. I know the regex needs validation work, but just testing out this particular function

Expected:

"04/05/2018 17:14:35" " -(Additional comments) update"

Actual:

"04/05/2018 17:14:35 -(Additional comments) update"

What I tried:

```
string <- "04/05/2018 17:14:35 -(Additional comments) update"

pattern <- "[:digit:][:digit:][:punct:] 
            [:digit:][:digit:][:punct:]
            [:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]
            [[:space:]]
            [:digit:][:digit:]
            [:punct:]
            [:digit:][:digit:]
            [:punct:]
            [:digit:][:digit:]"

strsplit(string, pattern)
```

I also tried this variation, same result

```
pattern <- "[:digit:][:digit:]\\/  
            [:digit:][:digit:]\\/
            [:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]             
            [[:space:]]
            [:digit:][:digit:]
             \\:
             [:digit:][:digit:]
             \\:
             [:digit:][:digit:]"
```

Comment: Why not use `el(strsplit(string, "[-]"))` to split on the `-` character?  You could also use the `tidyverse` function `separate` on your dataframe in the same manner [(link)](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
string <- "04/05/2018 17:14:35 -(Additional comments) update"


gsub("(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*","\\1", string)
#[1] "04/05/2018 17:14:35"

#RHS part
gsub("(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(.*)","\\2", string)
#" -(Additional comments) update"
```

Regex explanation:

- `\\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `\\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `/`      - separator
- `:`      - separator
- `()`     - Group for selection
- `.*`     - Followed by anything

Seems OP is very keen on using `strsplit`. One option could be as:

```
strsplit(gsub("(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(.*)",
       paste("\\1","####","\\2",sep=""), string), split = "####")
# [[1]]
# [1] "04/05/2018 17:14:35"            " -(Additional comments) update"
```

Comment: The regex help is much appreciated. I am working this into a larger formula where I want to preserve the right hand information. I tried applying this to the strsplit function without success. Trying some more things now with this input.

Comment: @JenniferSchleicher You can try `gsub("(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})(.*)","\\2", string)` for RHS part

Comment: @JenniferSchleicher I have updated answer to include a way to even use `strsplit`. I have used `####` as `split` you can choose set of character of your choice so that it wont clash with actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sub('-.*','',string)
[1] "04/05/2018 17:14:35 "
```